# Sending POST parameters to a URI

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I can't find a sample on how to do it with Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient...
I'd need to send to my webserver some user generated data which is unsafe to send via GET. It's not XML, they are just some couples name/value (so I can read them with $_POST[] in php)

Comment: Sending data as POST instead of GET does not add much security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that doing this, (I haven't tested):

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://application:9000/");

    FormUrlEncodedContent formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
       new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key1", "value"),
       new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key2", "value")
    });

    var response = httpClient.PostAsync("service.php", formContent);

    if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        string content = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
```

**Note**

A very interesting example, on how to send json data on a POST request using the HttpClient class can be found [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-use-HttpClient-to-b9289836/sourcecode?fileId=101048&pathId=2023847562), although you don't ask how to send json, the example per si, is interesting and will probably give you further understanding on how to use the HttpClient to send POST requests.

Comment: Do not use `var result = client.PostAsync(...).Result;`. That may block the thread, instead use `var result = await client.PostAsync(...);`

Comment: Also, I think you are mixing `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` and `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`. In the second one there is no `BaseAddress`, and `PostAsync` receives a `Uri` ;)